# How to reduce line space in node labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, nodes

How do I reduce the space between `Drill` and `$0` in the node?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
[grow = right, sibling distance = 6em, level distance = 10em, align=center, sloped] 
  \node {Decision} 
    child {node {No Drill\\\$0} } 
    child {node {Drill\\-\$1 million} 
      child {node {Oil\\\$4 million} edge from parent node [above] {.6} } 
      child {node {No Oil\\\$0} edge from parent node [above] {.4} } 
      }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, could you provide a MWE ? http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Comment: With your  (pseudo) MWE I can't reproduce your image.  Text in nodes are normally tied together. Do you have somewhere in document defined baseline stretch bigger than 1?

Comment: Please paste the full preamble.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86729)

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful advice. I didn't know that if I double-space my document that the spacing would also apply to node labels, so I single-spaced my document where the decision tree exists and it fixes the problem. Thanks, y'all!

Comment: @Zarko Do you want to answer?

Comment: @cfr, I just made an answer. Hopefully it will help someone.

Answer (score 6):

With your MWE I can't reproduce your image. Text in nodes are normally vertical spaced:

[image]

I guess, that in your document you have in preamble determined bigger baseline stretch, something like `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}`, which gives approximately the same image as you show in the your question:

[image]

The cure against this vertical stretching  (probably required line in the main text) is locally reduced back.  This can be achieved with `\linespread{1}` inside TikZ picture. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}% <--- probably it is in your document preamble 
                                  % or it is invoked with some option in 
                                  % \documentclass{...} which you use in your document. 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[grow = right, sibling distance = 6em, level distance = 10em, align=center, sloped]
%---
\linespread{1}% <--- locally defined vertical line spacing in nodes
%---
  \node {Decision}
    child {node {No Drill\\\$0} }
    child {node {Drill\\-\$1 million}
      child {node {Oil\\\$4 million} edge from parent node [above] {.6} }
      child {node {No Oil\\\$0} edge from parent node [above] {.4} }
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives the same picture as is show above on the first place. If you like to have even more tightly vertically spaced lines, you can select `linespread` smaller than 1, but at `\linespread{0.7}` lines start to overlaps.

And one more remark. Don't change font size in the node. For example, in your case:

```
...
child {node {\footnotesize Drill\\-\$1 million}
...
```

This will make smaller font in node text, but will not change baseline spacing, which stay accommodate to normal font size. Consequently the vertical space between lines will virtually increase. If you have need to reduce font only in one node, than make this with node's parameters:

```
...
child {node[font=\footnotesize] { Drill\\-\$1 million}
...
```

Which adopt line spacing in node text to (local) size of used fonts.

**Edit:** For sake of completeness (as suggest cfr in his comment): in many cases for increased vertical space between text lines is used package `setspace`, which provide between others  `\onehalfspacing` and `\doublespacing` commands as well as environment `\begin{singlespace} ... \end{singlespace}`. In this case you can write:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspace

\begin{document}
    \begin{singlespace}% <--- change spacing
\begin{tikzpicture}
[grow = right, sibling distance = 6em, level distance = 10em, align=center, sloped]
  \node {Decision}
    child {node {No Drill\\\$0} }
    child {node {Drill\\-\$1 million}
      child {node {Oil\\\$4 million} edge from parent node [above] {.6} }
      child {node {No Oil\\\$0} edge from parent node [above] {.4} }
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{singlespace}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks! You might want to mention **setspace**.

Comment: @cfr, see edit of my answer (if `setspace` is correct described).

Comment: That looks right. The point about **setspace** is it makes some corrections when the line spacing is changed which don't get made if you adjust the line spacing manually.